# Routing between 2 VLANs with one HP Switch

Tags: vlan, trunk

I need help with VLAN:

I have a WiFi AP with the IP 192.168.100.190. There are 2 SSIDs with VLAN 1 and 2 created. As a router I have a Sophos UTM with the IP 192.168.100.199. Furthermore, I have an HP 2530 switch with the following config:

```
trunk 14 trk1 trunk
ip default-gateway 192.168.100.199
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   untagged 1-13,15-28,Trk1
   ip address dhcp-bootp
   exit
vlan 2
   name "Guest"
   tagged 5,Trk1
   no ip address
   exit
spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
```

The router hangs on port 14 and the access point on port 5.

The VLAN 1 works fine with wireless, but in the guest VLAN 2 I get no connection - neither to the switch nor to the router let alone the Internet.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:**

Now I have the config like this:

```
ip default-gateway 192.168.100.199
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   untagged 1-28
   ip address dhcp-bootp
   exit
vlan 2
   name "Guest"
   tagged 5,14
   no ip address
   exit
spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
```

but it does not work anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HP trunk is not the same as a Cisco trunk.   In HP world, a trunk is what Cisco calls a port-channel.

You need vlan 1 untagged on port 14 and vlan 2 tagged on 14.

Comment: Now it works. The config was good. It was a wrong setting in the Sophos.